# Infinite scroll only works one time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I am building this webapp with React, in which there is a page with posts. I am trying to implement Infinite Scroll functionality manually and it seems to be working only one time.

When I have the last element on my window, it calls the api to fetch more posts, but when I update the state and get to "new" last post, it doesn't fetch any more posts. I believe I am really close to fixing this but I need a little guidance from you guys.

Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
 this.props.getPosts(this.state.page); //for the first load of the page 

 this.scrollListener = window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
        this.handleScroll(e)
 })

handleScroll = (e) => {
        let loadMoreElement = document.querySelector('.postGrid > div:last-child');
        var rect = loadMoreElement.offsetTop + loadMoreElement.clientHeight;
        var pageOffset = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight + 200;
        if(pageOffset > rect && !finished && !this.state.loading) {
            this.loadMore()
            this.props.getPosts(this.state.page)
            if(!this.state.has_more){ //has_more it's been set by the API when you get to the last page
                finished = true
                console.log("done")
            }
        } else if (finished){
            console.log("done")
        }}

    loadMore = () => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            page: prevState.page + 1,
            loading: true,
        }))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `loading` to true in your `loadMore` method, but one of the conditions to call `loadMore` again is if the `loading` is false (`!this.state.loading`)

You will need to set `loading` to false again at some point (*if there is api calls involved*) or just skip the `loading:true` part if you work with local data.

Comment: I am setting it to false in Redux file dataActions while I am updating the state. When the state is updated and when I get at the last post it seems like the loadMore isn't being called again (but handleScroll still works). I checked that because I console.log(e) and it still gets the window in console